# using underscore for a variable as same as keyword name in python

Tags: python, keyword

when you want to use some variable that has the same name as one of the keywords in Python, should I use `_keyword` or `keyword_`?

I know we should use underscore to not mess up with it but I am not sure about the position of the underscore. Does the position of underscore matter and mean anything?

For example, I am not sure which one (`True_` or `_True`)?

Or in other cases, when you want to use the name of a built-in function as one of your variables in your projects, what should you do? For example, I work with stock data, I have an open variable within my stock variables. So should I write `open_` or `_open`?

What about when you want to use these kinds of variables/methods in a class? Does it matter now where you use underscores?

Comment: Note that open is not a keyword.

Comment: Not the best example, since you can use `open` as a variable name since it is *not a keyword* but a *built-in*. That being said, it is also good practice not to shadow built-ins and where you put the underscore is part convention and part taste. A leading underscore sorta indicates a variable you are either not gonna use or should not rely on.

Comment: It matters if you use it in class. For example "_open" means that variable/method is private and should not be used in public.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! but even if I use open without any underscore, it will mess up with open built-in function and I do not want that either

Comment: `True_` or `_True`? Easy answer: definitely `true`!

Comment: you should also think about giving arguments more meaningful names. instead of  `_True` for example, you could use something like `is_capital`. After a while you will get a sense for that.

Comment: @Bartosz Karwacki, could you please explain it more

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are saying for a keyword it does not matter(True_ or _True) but for function, it does matter because of class and ...?

Comment: `True_` is a very bad example, since it uses class naming convention. The only somewhat official guideline, PEP 8, would reject both `True_` and `_True` for variables.

Comment: @Sarah https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/

Comment: @ Bartosz Karwacki, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in https://pep8.org/#function-and-method-arguments

> If a function argument’s name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus **`class_`** is better than clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

Note that a prefix underscore e.g. `_class` usually implies a private class attribute or method, something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_private_variable = 1

    def _my_private_method(self):
        pass
```

Some further info in https://pep8.org/#descriptive-naming-styles

> **`_single_leading_underscore`**: weak “internal use” indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
>
> **`single_trailing_underscore_`**: used by convention to avoid conflicts
> with Python keyword

Comment: Good find in the peps. Funny example they use as much of the Python world uses `klass` a lot for that particular case :)

Comment: I have never seen `klass`, but a lot of `cls`.